# How to match and replace key/value expression with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to match a pattern like `#key = *` and replace it with `key = 1` using sed and regular expressions.

This is my command:

```
sed -r -e "s/#\s*key\s*=\s*[^\n]*/key\s*=\s*1/g /tmp/test.txt"
```

but it's giving me the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'
```

What does that mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Show us your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input file name is not part of the `-e`, it should be a separate argument.

Also, `\s` in the output doesn't create whitespace, but you can capture the whitespace from the input with `(...)` and output it with the corresponding `\N`.

```
sed -r -e 's/#(\s*)key(\s*)=(\s*).*/key\2=\31/g' /tmp/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '#key = *' | sed -r -e 's/#\s*key\s*=\s*[^\n]*/key = 1/'
key = 1
```

Is this what you expect?